# Why does processor check say "compatible with long mode", but VMplayer is saying "incompatible"?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, vmware-player

When I open a Windows Server 2003 VM using VMware Player, there's an error message:

> [–§–](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCzYZ.png)  Software virtualization is incompatible with long mode on this platform. Disabling long mode. Without long mode support, the virtual machine will not be able to run 64bit code. For more details see http://vmware.com/info?id=152.

The link above brings us to a VMware article offering the download for [Processor Check for 64-Bit Compatibility](https://my.vmware.com/group/vmware/details?dlg=processor_check_5_5_dt&baseCode=dCpiQGhkYmRAZQ==).  Running, the processor check, it shows that there's no problems:

[image]

Why is VMware giving the error "incompatible with long mode" then?

How do we fix this error?

(If relevant, Vmware player is on Windows 8.1 64 bit with processor Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4510U CPU @ 2.00GHz, 2601 Mhz, 2 Cores, 4 Logical Processors.)

Comment: I'm tempted to say "Try another VM software and see if it works". Maybe windows 2003 is missing something that's needed - windows 8 needs pae (for 32 bit) nx and some other thing I forget.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Yes, vt-d is for direct io, that would not prevent the vm to create/boot. I seen the same exact error as the OP on a lab computer at home, VT-x was not available on the motherboard. (atom chipset)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vt-x/virtualisation must be enabled in the BIOS. I got the same symptom on a machine with a motherboard that does not support vt-x.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it, The issue here is that even though virtualization is disabled in BIOS, VMware Processor Check still says "Compatibility Check Passed", so I guess this is a bug with VMware Processor Check. I restarted into BIOS, enabled VT, and the error message is no longer there.

Comment: @Pacerier - Glad to hear it work ! :) I agree it's surely a bug, as for me the option wasnt even possible in the BIOS, so I guess it check the CPU, or a internal database of model to see if it can fit.